# What POP [BP-SI-80] is doing? 16bit assembly

Tags: assembly

I trying to understand this command, couse I have 2 different opinions.

Is `POP [BP-SI-80]` saving a some word from stack on `DS:[BP-SI-80]` or `SS:[BP-SI-80]`?

Comment: The later because BP is the base. However you're probably disassembling data not actual code that's meant to do something.

Comment: Note that it's probably `[BP+SI-80]` or `[BP+SI+80]`. There is no addressing mode with `BP-SI`.

Answer (score 6):

If `BP` is the register in a memory operand, the default segment is `SS`. This can be overridden with a segment prefix.

However, note that no addressing mode with `BP-SI` exists. You probably made a typo, the correct addressing mode is either `[BP+SI-80]` or `[BP+SI+80]`. Here is the encoding for you to compare:

```
8f 42 b0     pop [bp+si-80]
8f 42 50     pop [bp+si+80]
```

In case your assembler interpretes `80` as a hexadecimal constant, it is

```
8f 42 80     pop [bp+si-80h]
8f 82 80 ff  pop [bp+si-80h]
8f 82 80 00  pop [bp+si+80h]
```

Note that `[BP+SI-80h]` appears twice because there are two ways to encode it.

Comment: ohh, of course that was a typo, correct is bp+si :)

Comment: if I have on a stack i.e. 123h and DS=4000h, SS=1000h, SI=1h, BP=1111h and I have command POP[BP+SI]. So word 123h will be saved in [1000:1111]=[11111] ?

Comment: @AdrianWąt almost, but no, you either forgot to add `si`, or you are still misunderstanding it. (all values are hexa) `bp+si = 1111 + 0001 = 1112` => `[1000:1112 = 11112] = 23, [1000:1113 = 11113] = 01`.

Comment: ehh I was sleepy I forgot again to add something - of course you have right :)